# How would I use a control to get info from another page part of the same masterfile

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, master-pages

I have a Masterfile that has a header control with a button, and the ContentPlaceHolder which would be another page with multiple text boxes.

When I press the button in the header, I need to iterate through all the text boxes and grab their text, how exactly would I do this using C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the ContentPlaceHolder for null and if that succeeds, loop through all of the placeholder's controls, grabbing the text from all the TextBoxes. Alternatively, you could use the ContentPlaceHolder's `FindControl` method.

Comment: Note that with MasterPages, the FindControl method needs to be recursive, because the page hierarchy changes:
http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/5127.aspx

Comment: Also it would be safe to first check if the control is a TextBox before grabbing the text if iterating.